# Error al unir nodos en un cluster de Galera con Mysql en un servidor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-server, cluster

Mi proyecto consta de la realización de un clúster de Galera con MySQL en ubuntu 20.04. El problema se me ha generado a la hora de unir los nodos (tengo 3) al mysql: el nodo principal no me da ningún problema pero tanto el nodo2 como el nodo3 me dan problemas a la hora de unirlos. El error que me da es el siguiente:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Cant connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/log/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

He probado infinidad de cosas que he visto por internet pero ninguna consigue arreglarme este error.

Adjunto fotos tanto de los pasos del nodo1 como del nodo2 donde sale el error, una foto de la configuración del clúster (es en todos la misma) y una del log con los errores.[image: Nodo2][image: Nodo1][image: LOG error][image: Configuración Cluster]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Disculpa es mi primera vez y me urge solucionar esto. No sabía que existía esa guia